New rimless toilet splashing up
I had a new toilet installed and it's rimless the cistern was moved to attic. The issue is with the flush sometimes the water splashes up.
I need some sort or restrictor to slow down flow. Anyone link the item I need?
Cheers

It is my understanding that the splash is an unpleasant consequence of the rimless toilet.  Perhaps contact the installer or manufacturer regarding a solution.  Sorry but I know of none.
